# sql join - include non existent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, runtimes where I store runtimes and temps where I store temperatures.
I want to fetch temperature for all items on all runtimes.
If an item is missed on a runtime I want it to be shown as below.

**table runtimes**

```
runtimeId | time
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00
    2     | 2014-04-03 12:00:00
```

**table temps**

```
temps | itemId | runtimeId
 10   |    1   |     1
 20   |    2   |     1
 11   |    1   |     2
```

**Wanted result**

```
runtimeId | time                | temps | itemId 
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 |   10  |   1
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 |   20  |   2
    2     | 2014-04-03 12:00:00 |   11  |   1
    2     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 | NULL  |   2     <--
```

The part I don't manage is to get the last row.

Cheers

Comment: If your table "temps" does not contains a line with itemid = 2 and runtimeId = 2, it is not possible to get it with a join.

Comment: Your Statement: If an item missed in Runtimes table.
And, your example shows something got missed in temps.

Are you asking correct quesion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to your request:

```
select 
r.runtimeId,r.time,
(select temps from temps where runtimeId=r.runtimeId and itemId=data.itemId) as temps,
data.itemId
from 
runtimes r, 
(select distinct itemId from temps) data
order by r.runtimeid, data.itemid
```

It gives you the wanted result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc9e1/5

```
runtimeId | time                | temps | itemId 
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 |   10  |   1
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 |   20  |   2
    2     | 2014-04-03 12:00:00 |   11  |   1
    2     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 | NULL  |   2    <<<<<  preserves itemId 2
```

Especially the **runtimeId=2 and itemId=2** result row. It selects all `runtimes` with all `itemIds`.

I inserted an `order by` to get the sorting you suggested in your request.

Comment: Well, thats one way to force the issue. Cant say as I like the result.    Subselects in the select are not maintainable and you've just made a cartesian product here so it wont scale well.  But, you did get the right answer :) +1

Comment: You are right, but the cartesian product was requested in the OP: "for all items on all runtimes".

Answer (score 2):

A left join will show you all the records from the temps table as well as the records for the runtimes table.

```
select
  *
from
  runtimes rt
  left join temps t on rt.runtimeId = t.runtimeId
```

You've indicated that you want to see `itemId` 2 that matches `runtimeId` 2.

Nothing joins in your data this way however, so the 2 indicated with the arrow would be null.

Your result would be:

```
runtimeId | time                | temps | itemId 
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 |   10  |   1
    1     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 |   20  |   2
    2     | 2014-04-03 12:00:00 |   11  |   1
    2     | 2014-04-02 12:00:00 | NULL  |   NULL
```

For a cartesian product that will show itemId regardless of its relation to the other table, see @wumpz answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.runtimeId, r.time, t.temps, t.itemId from runtimes r
left outer join temps t on r.runtimeId = t.runtimeId
```

Comment: according to the data, it will not work as there is no line in "temps" with itemid = 2 and runtimeId = 2

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
select r.runtimeid,r.time, t.temps, t.itemId from runtime r left join temps t 
on r.runtimeid=t.runtimeid
```